# Trying to find data from an entry that is a given period earlier when that doesn't match up?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the poor wording with the question, but I didn't know how to ask it succinctly. Basically, I am working with a database that has entries spanning almost a century, and one of the calculations I want to carry out relies on selecting data from, say 10 years prior. The issue, though, is that not every date is covered in this time period. For these dates I would want to grab data from the nearest date that is recorded ~10 years prior. So, if I'm looking at: 04-25-1999 and there is no entry on 04-25-1989, I would want to instead select from 04-24-1989 or 04-26-1989. Is there any way to do this in SQL? Thanks!

EDIT:
I have this

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 4/23/1989 | 10.5 |
| 4/24/1989 | 13 |
| 4/27/1989 | 12 |
| 4/28/1989 | 11.5 |
| ... | ... |
| 4/24/1999 | 21 |
| 4/25/1999 | 23 |
| 4/26/1999 | 22.5 |
| 4/28/1999 | 22 |

I would want this:

| Date | Price | Price (10 y/o) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4/24/1999 | 21 | 13 |
| 4/25/1999 | 23 | 13 |
| 4/26/1999 | 22.5 | 12 |
| 4/28/1999 | 22 | 11.5 |

Comment: Yes this is possible. But in order to offer any real advice you need to provide some details. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just added some extra information -- does that help?

Comment: Do you want to get the nearest date? What do you want when there's 1 day before and 1 day after?

Comment: yes, nearest date. I could default to 1 day before being preferable over 1 day after, or if that is too complicated just keep going before until you hit a date that matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not difficult to find the nearest date. This approach is hopefully more efficient than searching across the entire history by limiting to a range of dates around the 10-year lookback. If you can guarantee that a date will be found within a fixed window of some size then this ought to be fast.

```
select "Date", Price, Price10YO
from T t1 cross apply (
    select top 1 Price as Price10YO from T t2
    where t2."Date" between
            dateadd(day, -14, dateadd(year, -10, t1."Date"))
        and dateadd(day, +14, dateadd(year, -10, t1."Date"))
    order by
        abs(datediff(day, t2."Date", dateadd(year, -10, t1."Date")),
        t2."Date"
) as p
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cec630d75ad56aa20a9db7f178d4ed96